# How to solve directory must be writable recursively issue in Larave5.4?

Tags: laravel

I am facing one issue while installing database and images on live server in laravel 5.4. I made folder permissions(777) but again I am facing below error.

```
The directory must be writable (recursively) by the web server (0775).
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a parent directory has a more restrictive octal?

Comment: Look here I guess [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others) will help you!

Comment: use `chmod` command with `-R` option to recursively set permissions.

Comment: I did not get you @Quezler.

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva, it is possible with ftp or any other way? I don't have terminal on live server.

Comment: @Developerajay using ssh to server

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva, Okay I will check it.

Comment: Try this after you have run the composer update:

php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Try to set -Rf permissions for specific folder and then try php artisan cache:clear

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd, I will try this. Thank you for reply.